# How to get the total row count?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to get total row count in iReport. The intention is to print a label based on the total row count.

My Format is like this (Assume that there are 10 records):

```
    This is page 1

    No Name Add
    1  ---- ---
    2  ---- ---
    3  ---- ---
    4  ---- ---
    5  ---- ---

    cont...2


    This is page 2

    No Name Add
    6  ---- ---
    7  ---- ---
    8  ---- ---
    9  ---- ---
    10 ---- ---
```

How do I get all record count before printing the report?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the built-in variable iReport `$V{REPORT_COUNT}`.

Also, if you're interested in the final value, set the text field's evaluation time to "Report".

Answer (score 2):

Put the `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` in the detail section of your report along with your other fields.

It will display the values in sequence as you mentioned in your question.

1. create a variable drag and drop
2. in the detail section right click on the item
3. click on edit expressions
4. in fx variables you will see `REPORT_COUNT`